# 翻訳の管理をメタ以外の場所でやるのはどうか

Tags: 機能の要求, 翻訳

具体的にはTransifexやCrowdinなどの有料サービスや、WeblateやPootleなどの翻訳管理ツールを立てて使うのはどうでしょうか。

メリット

- メタではサイトの運用に関する議論に集中できる
- 翻訳に特化したUIの方が使いやすい

  - メタは単語やフレーズレベルの小さな文言についての意志決定を意図して作られていない

    - 翻訳案を投稿しようとすると、回答は最低20文字必要というバリデーションにひっかかったりする
- 原文を見ながら翻訳できる
- SEスタッフが翻訳案を反映する手間が省ける

デメリット

- メタしか見ないユーザーと翻訳ツールユーザーとの分断?
- 翻訳ツールとSEプラットフォームを統合する手間がかかる
- 一般的な翻訳ツールは、ヘルプセンターのような、ページ単位の記事の翻訳には向いていない

  - ヘルプセンターはWiki化してしまうのがよいかもしれない

Comment: 複数の言語でSOを作成する前に、翻訳を「crowd-sourcing」を検討していましたが、社内の議論では否定の意見が多かったです。ツールを作成するにも時間もかかるし、翻訳の裏に技術面では問題が多くなることも可能です。再検討は可能ですが、実現性は少ないと想像します（数週間で翻訳を開発者と議論していますが、ちょっと難しい部分が多そう）