# 翻訳バグのワークフローを改善しましょう

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

英語以外の言語に乗り出した時、当社の考え方がかなり甘かったです。「プロの翻訳者に頼めば、なんとか一発で言語の問題が解決できる」と思っていましたが、残念ながらそのぐらい簡単にできませんでした。結果的に[翻訳のバグが１００以上](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3)登録されていますし、仕組み上弊職しか対応出来ないため、解決までに時間がかかります。

[image: Engrish 2]
<sup>*やっぱり、翻訳は難しいね*</sup>

翻訳に関わる問題は複数あります：

1. 当サイトの[専門用語](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/stack-overflow%e3%81%ae%e5%b0%82%e9%96%80%e7%94%a8%e8%aa%9e)は簡単に翻訳できない
2. 翻訳の更新は社員しかできない仕組みになっている
3. 日本語が話せる社員は一人しかいない
4. 英語版のサイトの文言が頻繁に更新される
5. メタは翻訳を管理する目的で作られていない

この問題を解決するには、コミュニティの皆様へ<s>丸投げする</s>支援できるツールを提供するしかないです。

#### ようこそ、Transifexへ

[Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/)というのはOpen Sourceソフトウェアなど、複数の翻訳者がいるプロジェクトを管理するためのシステムです。当サイトのすべてのストリングがアップされているので、システム上で新しい翻訳を提案することも、他の人の翻訳にプラス票・マイナス票を入れることもできます。

当コミュニティから承認者を選び、その人が「OK」を出せば、弊職がサイトへ適用します。（弊職個人の意見としては[３ヶ月間前にこのシステムを提案されたentoさん](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286/)にするべきですが、他の提案があればご教示ください）。

#### 翻訳の新ワークフロー

1. 翻訳プロジェクトに興味がある方は[Transifexに登録してください](https://www.transifex.com/signin/)（当サイトと同じメールアドレスを使用していただけるとベストです）
2. このメタ投稿へのコメントでTransifexのユーザー名を教えてください（当サイトに登録されているメールアドレスをプロジェクトに招待します）
3. 翻訳についてのメタ投稿をTransifexに適用し、[チャットで弊職／承認者に知らせてください](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/)

もちろん、これはめんどくさそうと思ったら、従来どおりメタに投稿すれば大丈夫です（[翻訳](/questions/tagged/%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3)タグを忘れずに！）。

Comment: 現状でも、特にステータスやリワード系メッセージで英語の原文が出現しますが、メタに投稿すると際限がないなと思ってパスしていました。私はたまに [ソフトウェアの翻訳](https://github.com/hyamamoto/phabricator-l10n/commits/phabricator-ja/src/infrastructure/internationalization/translation/PhabricatorBaseJapaneseTranslation.php) をすることがあり、ツールは揃えていますのでこういうやり方の方が楽です。手伝わせてくださるなら空き時間に未翻訳のところに手を付けたいと思います。 /// TransifexUsername=hyamamoto

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto [status-\*]のタグは元日本語訳はありましたが、開発者が読めなかったため、とりあえず英語に戻しました。[status-\*]のストリングはTransifexに入っていないです（変えることができますが、開発者に直接連絡する必要はあります）

Comment: 了解そういうものはメタ投稿ですね。 (残り頻繁に気になっているのは INBOX の英語メッセージと 「 [プロフィール > activities > 推奨](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activities&sort=suggestions) 」の承認関連ぐらい…)

Comment: 私は気になります。日本語が少し出来ますが、頑張って手伝ってみます。 TransifexUsername=antimo

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto 数百英語のストリングが残っています。時間かかりましたが、一発で適当に治すより、継続できる仕組みを考えようとしましたので、お待たせしました。

Comment: 協力できたらと思います。TransifexUsername=madapaja

Comment: `unarist`でお願いします。Transifexの方でもリクエストを送りましたがこちらでも。

Comment: TransifexUsername=aterai で参加申請します(Transifexで誤って「言語を申請」してしまったのですが、取り消す方法が無いみたいで...、すいません)。

Comment: ユーザー名`h2so5`で申請します。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 参加ありがとうございます！皆様は追加したと思いますが、もしアクセス出来ない場合にはご教示ください。よろしくお願いします！

Comment: 承認者としての追加ありがとうございます。Transifex上でもユーザー名はentoです。全体をみた判断を心がけます。

Comment: @jmac TransifexUsername=tomute です。協力します。

Comment: `riocampos` で Transifex に登録しました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: User `snipsnipsnip` で参加します。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @snipsnipsnip 遅れて申し訳ないです。今まで伝えた皆様へ招待しました。

Comment: `3100`でTransifexに登録しましたので申請します。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @3100 招待を送りました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `hinaloe`で申請します。お願いします。

Comment: @hinaloe 追加しました。

Comment: 今更ですが`user10685`で参加します。よろしくお願いします

Comment: @user10685 よろしくお願いします！

Comment: @jmac 招待メールが届いていないようです。お手数ですが再送お願いします

Comment: @user10685 すみませんでした！承認がうまくいかなかったです。先に追加しました。よろしくお願いします！

Answer (score 5):

Transifexの使い方ではっきり決まっていないことや、直近でやった方がよさそうことをリストアップします。

1. ストリングがどういう文脈で使われているのかを確認したい時はどうするか

   ひとまず[翻訳チャットルーム](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/)で聞けばよいでしょうか？と思ったら[文脈情報は分からない](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20086496#20086496)のですね。あたりをつけて翻訳してみて、おかしいところを後で直していくというのでもいい気もしますが、他の言語の翻訳者も同じように悩むかもしれないことを考えると、文脈が不明確なものは開発者さんにストリングの [`description`](http://docs.transifex.com/developer/formats/chrome_json) に文脈情報を入れていってもらうのがいいようにも思います。

   [Transifex Live](http://docs.transifex.com/developer/integrations/partnerintegrations#how-transifex-live-works)を導入したら解決する問題なのかもと期待していますが、これは翻訳UIの提供だけでなく、実際の翻訳までJSでやってしまう全部入りパッケージにも見えます。翻訳UIだけを使うことができれば実際の画面を見ながら翻訳できて便利そうです。
2. Transifexのディスカッションボードを使うか

   そちらは今のところ使わず、話し合いが必要なことはひとまずメタと[翻訳チャットルーム](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/)で進めてみてよいかなと思います。Transifexにユーザー登録していない人にも伝わりやすいところでやり取りしたいです。

   追記: 使いどころとしては、翻訳関連のメタ投稿をお知らせするなど、チームメンバーに確実に何かを伝えたい時になりそうです。

   また個々のストリングについての話し合いはTransifex上のコメント欄でいい気がします。必要に応じてチャットやメタにエスカレートで。
3. Transifex上の用語集（Glossary）の整備

   [Glossary](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/glossary/l/ja/)は誰でも追加編集できるようです。[専門用語をまとめた](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/stack-overflow%e3%81%ae%e5%b0%82%e9%96%80%e7%94%a8%e8%aa%9e)メタ投稿の内容を手始めとして、必要なものを追加していけばよいかなと思います。
4. スタイルガイドの整備

   ひとまず翻訳率を100%にすることを目指せばよいかなと思っていますが、全体的なクオリティアップのためにスタイルガイドも定めていきたいところです。表記ルールや全体的なトーン、ボタンのラベルや見出しの言い回しなど。

   参考になるもの: [日本翻訳連盟の標準スタイルガイド](http://www.jtf.jp/jp/style_guide/styleguide_top.html)や[ウィキペディアのスタイルマニュアル](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%83%9E%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A5%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB)、[マイクロソフトのスタイルガイド](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/ja-jp/StyleGuides.aspx)。
5. バッジの名前決め

   [バッジの名前についてのメタ投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1505/30)に案が集まっています。バッジはユーザーの一種の持ち物であり、サイト上の他の文言とは性格が違うものなので、扱いも別にした方がいいのではと思います。

   Transifex翻訳チーム内で揉む → コミュニティーのフィードバックをもらう → 適用

   など。

Comment: 「お礼」など、現在使われている訳に変更案が出ている場合は用語集に入れにくいと思うのですが、これは別途メタやチャットで決めることになるのでしょうか。

Comment: あとメタで特定の語の翻訳について言及する際、Transifex側で識別できるもの（一覧で表示される数字？詳細で表示されるキー？）を貼っておくといいかもしれません。

Comment: パーフォーマンスのため、ストリングはコンパイル時に入れていますので、Transifex Liveを使えないです。「description」は自動的に当社のDBからTransifexへ移動するために上書きになってしまうので、それも良い解決方ではないです。ディスカッションボード・Glossary・スタイルガイドがベストだと思います。ツーステップでバッジ等をメタで確認したい場合、それも大歓迎です。

Comment: @unarist 残念ながら、Transifex側でのキーが当社のDBからアップするごとに変わってくるのが事実です。英語が更新されたら、新しいストリングが追加させますし、旧ストリングが削除されると想定しています。

Comment: @unarist たしかに「お礼」などの変更案の判断も必要ですね。翻訳者同士の認識合わせが必要なので、メタかなあと思います。各用語が使われている箇所を検索できるようになったので、文脈に合う表現を考えやすくなりましたね。

Comment: @unarist 翻訳画面のURLは、[選択中のストリングのパーマリンクになっている](http://blog.transifex.com/post/70201060672/5-secret-features-in-transifex)そうです。URLをそのまま使うか、URLの最後のIDを共有すればよさそう

Comment: @jmac ストリングをコンパイル時に入れる動作はそのままで、翻訳者向けのUIだけをTransifex Liveで作れないかなと考えました。そういう需要はありそうなので、Transifexに相談したら開発してくれるかもしれません。description: [一部のストリング](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40284580)には description ("VARIANT: other") が入っているので、技術的には可能そうに見えます。

Comment: @ento `description:other`等は複数形関係です（自動的に付きます）。データベースにそれが入っているため、入れるのが簡単ですが、他の情報は相談しますが、難しいと思います。

Comment: @ento Transifex LiveはHTMLに原文が記載されていることを前提としてるみたいなので、本家SOの画面に日本語版の翻訳テーブルを適用して～みたいなことになる気がします。。