# 213件の未翻訳個所を一掃しましょう！

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

古いメタ投稿を見ると、最初の頃は当サイトの未翻訳ストリングは相当多かったです。

[皆様のおかげで](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1680)、[翻訳](/questions/tagged/%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3)のバグも少なくなりました！しかし、[Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english)を見ると、「まだ1500件も未翻訳なの・・・？」と思ってしまう人もいると思います。

この中には本家でテスト中の新機能など、当サイトで使われないストリングも多く含まれています。そこで翻訳者の時間を無駄しないように[新しいツールを作成しました](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing)。ここでは、サイトを閲覧しているユーザーが見かける未翻訳ストリングが表示回数が多い順に並んでいます。そしてストリングごとに、どこのページで現れるかや、Transifexへのリンクが載っています。

この213ストリングを順番に翻訳したら、当サイトを閲覧する99.9%のユーザー<sup>※1</sup>が未訳箇所に遭遇することはなくなります！

<sup>※1 実はこのような統計は非常に複雑なため、気持ちのいい数字を適当に選びました</sup>

Comment: ひとまずリストに載ってるフレーズのうち半分くらいは訳しましたが、そのリストっていつリセットされるんでしょうか？