# プロフィールの「次の権限」が英語のままになっている権限名がある

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

スタックオーバフローのプロフィールには次に得られる権限名が表示されます。
ですがスコア５００を超えたあたりから、この権限名が英語表記のまま残っているものが
いくつか見つかりました。

[image: 権限名が英語のまま]

これは正しい挙動なのでしょうか？
日本語の中に突然英語が現れて、すこしびっくりしましたのでできるなら改善をお願いしたいです。

Comment: 翻訳が失われたままほったらかしになってますね・・・対応します。（なので[meta-tag:機能の要求]より[meta-tag:バグ]の方が適切です： http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2160/8000）

Comment: Transifex上でunaristさんの変更を適用しましたが、まだ英語ですか？

Comment: @jmac 日本語に修正されました。助かります。

Answer (score 2):

Transifex上で翻訳を設定しました。併せて「[213件の未翻訳個所を一掃しましょう！](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2151/8000)」で挙がっている他の権限関連のフレーズについても一通り訳しましたが、もしまた見かけたらお知らせください。