# 「未翻訳のフレーズ」ページは機能していますか？

Tags: バグ, 却下, 翻訳

現在、[「未翻訳のフレーズ」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing)に何も表示されません。
これは、未翻訳のフレーズが無くなったことを意味しますか？
それともバグでしょうか。（MSEにおいて、バグだとする書き込みが[3年前にあります](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323989/untranslated-strings-page-is-empty#comment1058931_323989)）

---

Currently ["Missing Translations"](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing) has no item. Does this mean we don't have strings without translation any more? Or is this a bug? (I found that [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323989/untranslated-strings-page-is-empty#comment1058931_323989) on MSE three years ago says this is a bug.)

Note: This page was originally created [here](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2151/19110) in order not to translate unused strings.

Comment: Tagging this as [status-deferred] and adding it to the development team's backlog to be addressed as part of bug duty. As per [Nicolas's comment] this page is not used any more, so I'll leave a note explaining that and asking the development team to kill the page.（こちらのタグを [meta-tag:延期] と変更し、バグデューティローテーションの一環として対処できるよう開発チームのバックログに追加いたします。[ニコラスのコメント] によるとこのページはもう使用されていないのでそのことを説明し、開発チームにページ削除を依頼するメモを残す予定です。）

Answer (score 2):

https://ja.traducir.win/ で確認する限り strings without translation はまだまだゼロ件には遠いので、未翻訳のフレーズとして何も表示されないのはバグっぽい挙動に見えます。しかし実際には /translations/missing は既にメンテナンスされておらず、何も表示されないのが仕様のようです。

現状の翻訳は https://ja.traducir.win/ で行われているので、こちらを参照ください。

Comment: 以前に聞いた事には、transifex や traducir にあるメッセージの全てがスタックオーバフローで使われているわけでは無いらしいです。
どれ位が使われているかは解りませんが、もしかしたら半分以下とかかも知れません。
現状、7225/10645 が翻訳済みですから、日本語版スタックオーバフロー向けの翻訳が実際にほぼ終わっている可能性もあると思います。
つまり、これ以上メッセージを翻訳をしても、それは使われることの無いメッセージかも知れないという事です。
そういった無駄な労の発生を避けるため、 [/translation/missing が作られたという経緯があります](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2151/3054)。
今は事情が変わっているかも知れませんが、翻訳作業を続けるならば、確認した方がよいと思います。

Comment: （はい、すべてが使われていないのはその通りです。ただ表示されているのに未翻訳な string があることは分かっているので、ゼロ件かどうかは疑わしいです（モデレーターにしか表示されない string を未翻訳のまま残していたりします）。とりあえず Stack Exchange の社員さんに事実確認中です……。少々お待ちください）

Comment: This is correct, we do not use /translations/missing anymore. Thank you!（おっしゃる通りです。今はもう /translations/missing を使用しておりません。どうもありがとうございます！）

Answer (score 1):

こちらのステータスを[却下](/questions/tagged/%e5%8d%b4%e4%b8%8b)といたします。 現在のツールを用いて現在の私達のニーズに対応できており、修正するには翻訳管理システムの全面的な見直しが必要となる為、こちらを修正することができません。

---

I'm [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)'ing this. We are not going to be able to fix this right now as doing so will require a larger overhaul to the translation management system, and the current tools are usable for addressing our current needs.